# How not to show JQuery dialog until all related data is loaded?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a problem with JQuery dialog() showing before all the data ( text boxes, drop down menus etc..) are populated.

I simply call:

```
$("#myDiv").dialog("open") is called
```

and then  under dialog properties:

```
       $("#myDiv").dialog({
        title: "Edit User",
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
        modal: true,
        open: function(event,ui){
        url = "/controller/action" + param;
        $(this).load(url);

        ...various $.ajax and $.GetJson calls to populate form drop down menus and other fields...},
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function () {
            allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
        }
    });
```

So a dialog opens, after about a seconds blinks and gets populated with data. Sometimes it lags and the data doesn't go in the fields at all. I may have to close/reopen the dialog multiple times before it finally gets populated.
Very frustrating.

What's the easiest way to get this to work ? I want the dialog popup to be properly populated with data every time and not to be displayed until it's ready.

Comment: have you considered first making the ajax calls, then on the successful receiving of the data call the dialog? Even before all that you may want to throw up a loading animation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem:

```
        open: function(){
    ...various $.ajax and $.GetJson calls to populate form drop down menus and other fields...},
```

Don't populate on open, populate on create

```
create: function(){
    ...various $.ajax and $.GetJson calls to populate form drop down menus and other fields...},
```

Comment: The problem with that is that create triggers on Page load, not on when the dialog is about to pop. I don't know what info to load into the dialog until a specific link on the page is clicked.

Comment: Let me ask you this. Is there a way to force that "Create" event to trigger on demand ? Let's say when I click on a specific link and know what Id to pass to my popup ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) plugin and block before your Ajax/Json calls and Unblock after them. This will also allow you to show a loading div over the dialog.

```
$.blockUI()
// ajax/json calls
$.unblockUI();
```